# datetimepicker not showing timepicker after php upgrade

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a perfect working system under

**PHP Version  5.6.8**

**jquery.ui.timepicker.js**

Since they did and upgrade on the server to PHP Version 5.6.14
my calendar doesn't show the time picker anymore but show the month days and year.

this is how I call it:

```
$.fn.datetimepickerDom = function(){
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear:true,
            hour:0,
            minute:0,
            second:0,
            showAnim: "slideDown"
        });
```

I don't get any console mistake either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i dont think php server can mess with javascript plugins, they are server independent, debug your problem and see console or network

Comment: can you show us the line when including the timepicker library?

Answer (score 0):

Add close curly breket at end. So your code will be look as below

```
    $.fn.datetimepickerDom = function(){
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear:true,
            hour:0,
            minute:0,
            second:0,
            showAnim: "slideDown"
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end the problem was i was calling a php footer twice that included jquery 2 times, apareently in older php it only showed once